# Link to Accordion on a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, accordion

I have a set of accordions on a working page.  Linking to the tabs from the same page works.  I need to link to them from a different page.

Here is my JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['responsiveTabs'], function() {
    $('#Accordion_TabRepeater').responsiveTabs({
        collapsible: 'accordion',
        startCollapsed: 'accordion',
        scrollToAccordion: true,
        scrollToAccordionOnLoad: false,
        active: 0
    });
});
</script>
```

Accordion menu code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="text-col-container"><div id="Accordion_TabRepeater" class="responsiveTabs accordionGeenCircle noCounter">
    <ul class="tabMenu">
      <li>
<a href="#tab-1-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Academic Tuition and Fee Rates">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Academic Tuition and Fee Rates</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-2-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Rates for Frederick County High School Students">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Rates for Frederick County High School Students</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-3-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Academic Payment Due Dates - Drop Zone">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Academic Payment Due Dates - Drop Zone</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-4-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Options for Paying Your Academic Tuition">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Options for Paying Your Academic Tuition</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-5-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Work in Frederick County?">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Work in Frederick County?</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-6-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Refund Policy">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Refund Policy</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-7-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Continuing Education &amp; Workforce Development Payment">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Continuing Education &amp; Workforce Development Payment</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-8-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Past Due Balances/Collections">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Past Due Balances/Collections</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-9-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Student Account Forms">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Student Account Forms</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-10-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="1098-T FAQ">
  <span class="tab-item-title">1098-T FAQ</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span>
  
</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#tab-11-Accordion_TabRepeater" title="Financial Awareness Resources">
  <span class="tab-item-title">Financial Awareness Resources</span>
  <span class="ui-icon"></span> 
</a>
</li>
    </ul>
```

Accordion Content (just the first one - to save space here):

```
   <div class="tabPanels">
      <div class="tab-panel-counter-increment"></div>
<div id="tab-1-Accordion_TabRepeater">
  <h3 class="tab-panel-title">Academic Tuition and Fee Rates</h3>
  <div class="tab-panel-content">
    <p>To see the most recent tuition &amp; fees, visit <a href="https://www.frederick.edu/cost-financial-aid/tuition-fees.aspx" target="_blank">https://www.frederick.edu/cost-financial-aid/tuition-fees.aspx </a></p>
  </div>
```

Here is the page: https://www.frederick.edu/cost-financial-aid/student-accounts.aspx

If you hover over any of the accordions, you can see it's link.

For example, the third accordion link is:
https://www.frederick.edu/cost-financial-aid/student-accounts.aspx#tab-3-Accordion_TabRepeater

You can easily link and open this accordion IF on the same page. I want to be able to link to this accordion from another page.

Comment: Where is the code that is supposed to do the linking, both the version that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: Added additional code.